# Biofeedback and Neurofeedback: Scams or Real?

Tags: conditioning, biofeedback

I'm currently taking an AP Psychology course which just discussed biofeedback and neurofeedback very briefly. All I can say is that I'm entirely skeptical that either one works by any mechanism other than the Placebo Effect.

How is it possible for someone to consciously control one's own physiological processes just by being aware of the processes? Isn't this highly subjective and prone to the Placebo Effect?

Comment: Related: [Meditation - just spiritual practice or something more?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/922/meditation-just-spiritual-practice-or-something-more/928#928).

Comment: Voted to close, as there are a host of biofeedback measures available, each with their specific advantages and disadvantages with respect to validity

Comment: it would be nice to have a collection of information about advantages and disadvantages of different biofeedback.  i'm not sure myself where to go for such info.

Comment: @honi - it would be nice, but then the question needs to be focused. I am working my way into this field and would be happy to answer, but not within the question's current scope.